# Proof for a Statement on Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In my textbook after this theorem comes another statement(I wasn't sure to call it a theorem). The proof for the theorem is given but I don't know why the statement is true. Can you help me prove it?
**Theorem** If $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$. Therefore, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist, or exists but is not zero, then the series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$ is divergent.
**Statement** If the sequence of terms $\{a_n\}$ tends to a non-zero limit $L$, then $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n = 1}a_n$ diverges to infinity if $L > 0$ and diverges to negative infinity if $L < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L>0$, then there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies|a_n-L|<\frac L2\implies a_n>\frac L2.$$Therefore, if $n>N$,$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+\sum_{k=N+1}^na_k\geqslant\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+(n-N)\frac L2$$and so, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+(n-N)\frac L2=\infty,$$your series diverges to $\infty$. The argument is similar if $L<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: if your sequence $a_n$ converges to a positive number $L>0$, then the series, which is the sum of the infinite terms of the sequence, will come to a point where it will basically be summing $L$ an infinite number of times. This can only result in the series diverging to $+\infty$.

On the other hand, if $L<0$, you are adding a negative value an infinite number of times. This can only result in the series diverging to $-\infty$.

The only way that a series can converge is if it comes to a point where the infinite terms you are adding are basically equal to zero. This requires $L=0$.